# Reduce number of class files produced by BlackBerry app

Tags: blackberry, java-me

I have developed an order processing application for BlackBerry. When I look at the bin folder I see more than 100 `.class` files.

I have created a main screen class for adding new clients. The screen has 7 LabelField objects and 7 corresponding TextField objects. This screen also creates a VerticalFieldManager and adds all these fields to it and then adds the VerticalFieldManager to the screen.

For this screen, I have 14 `.class` files in the bin folder. It seems there is one class file for every field in the progam. 
For example:

```
NewClient.class
NewClient$1.class
...
NewClient$14.class
```

How do I design the UI in order to reduce the number of compiled classes?

Comment: Why is the number of `.class` files a problem for you?

Comment: `Premature optimization is the root of all evil`. Do not think about it until you have fully working application. Then think - why do you need this? BB RIM OS has limitation on object handles, but your application won't reach this limit unless you are not generating thousands on objects at the runtime. Qty of classes inside of your application is not a matter to worry about.

Comment: In my application I use custom class for design the application that why my $class file create I want to minimize this one plz give me some solution about it

Comment: There's no `solution`. Every thing like menuitem, custom field, etc - is a `visibly separate` object. Every thing like API field, screen, manager, etc is a separate object, which is not visible to you, but is visible to RIM OS upon the runtime. If you insist to not have classes, then use one class and use procedural approach. But I do not understand why do you need this.

Comment: Hi Rafael, Now currently on my bin folder there are 100 .class files due to this my application is not visible on 8520 simulator that why I want to reduce the creation of .class files plz help me

Comment: I've worked on projects with far more than 100 classes and they worked even on BB 7290 devices. There's something strange with your application and I think this strangeness is not related to number of class files. Make sure you have correct application descriptor with correct main class set, make sure your application does not fail on device startup, check logs, etc. Make your application simple, and add classes and complexity step by step and inspect the application behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set your jdk bin folder path on the environment variable path on right clicking on the myComputer icon

Then Restart the pc

Other way is to don't use overwrite method on your code such as

```
btmSave.setChangeListner(new FieldChangeListner()
{
   private void fieldChange()
   {
    }

}
);
```

Avoid This type of writing code it create your no of class Files on project bin folder

Answer (score 2):

Building a Java-ME app for BlackBerry is a two step process. First the java source code is compiled to class files, then those class files are compiled again into a .cod file, which can be deployed onto a simulator or a device.

'rapc' is the RIM compiler that takes java programs and turns them into a cod or alx file for deployment. 'rapc' can take either java source code, or compiled java classes.  Either way, it can produce output suitable for a device.

When starting with Java source files, you can explicitly compile them to class files and hand those class files to `rapc` or you can pass the Java source to rapc and it will compile the source directly.  `rapc` just defers to the JDK javac compiler when presented with java source code.  This means a standard java JDK compiler is always used as the first step of compiling a BlackBerry app, and we can look at standard java behavior to understand what is happening.

In Java, every class that is instantiated has exactly one `.class` file. For normal classes with a declared name, like this:

```
public class Foo extends Bar {
}
```

The `.class` file is assigned a name that matches the declared class name.  However, Java also allows anonymous classes.  These take the form of a `new Foo()` followed by a curly brace which turns this into an anonymous class. This presents a problem, as this anonymous class must be assigned a name at the VM level, despite having none at the Java source level.  The solution is to use a character that is invalid in Java source, but valid in the VM, namely `$`.  The anonymous classes are assigned a name based on the enclosing Java class, followed by `$`, then an integer index based on the number of anonymous classes ahead of this one. In your case, that is `NewClient`, followed by 14 distinct integers.

To see the behavior you describe, your fields must all actually be anonymous implementations of those classes you mention.  To reduce the number of classes, try reusing explicit classes, instead of writing custom behavior with each instantiation.